# Querying two databases at the same time using R

Tags: sql, r

Is it possible to make one query in which I have data from two databases.
For example:
The table in DB1 has 20M rows
The table in DB2 has 2k rows
When I combine them (using inner join) I will have about 2M rows. Is this possible without retrieving 20M and 10M rows before executing the query?

Comment: Unless the databases have a foreign-table connection (not common), then the answer is "no". The only way _you_ can avoid having to download all of the data before joining them is if one database talks directly to the other. That's a completely different discussion for the DBAs, and has nothing to do with R.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Presumably you could load the small DB2 table and use it to execute the join using only the relevant rows from DB1?

Comment: I like @JonSpring's suggestion: (1) download the smaller 2K dataset from DB2; (2) upload these 2K rows as a temporary table to DB1; (3) execute a join on DB1 against the bigger table and your temp table. (And in case you don't use a temp table or want to be explicit, (4) delete the temp table from DB1.)